# Map a custom type to database column

Tags: jpa, playframework

Let's say I have a model class A who has a member of class B which is not a model. How can make it so that class A can be saved as an entity and class B transformed into something more pleasent for the database such as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get it. You want to save an item but not use it as model? Plus, normally for non model/entity items, they are automatically transformed into binary format and saved.

If you really want "a more pleasant" format for the database, use an Model/Entity annotation.

Comment: I thought it would become very wasteful but I guess I better profile etc before caring about it.

Comment: Wastefull in what sense? You will indeed lose database indexation, etc. but if that concerns you, it should be an entity/model.

Comment: Yes and no. Indeed if you choose binary format, there will be no indexes. No indexes means a slower acces using that column. But if you need to access via that data, that means, you will use it as criteria. Which means, it is supposed to be an entity. If you are just concerned by the persistent part, don't worry about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Add to class A

String mystring = myB.toString();

then mystring will be persisted in your Model.

Comment: Hm, but then I would loose the level of abstraction wouldn't I? Or where do you mean that I should put it?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. If you need B to be retrieved when A is retrieved then you have to persist B. If performance is really an issue I would suggest you store B in PLay's cache and use lazy loading when loading A from the db.